# Python: interrogate database over http

Tags: python, database, http

I want to do automatic searches on a database (in this example www.scopus.com) with a simple python script. I need some place from where to start. For example I would like to do a search and get a list of links and open the links and extract information from the opened pages. Where do I start?

Comment: I would like to know first of all where to start. I was considering https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm is it a correct way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, scopus.com is not "a database", it's a web site that let's you search / consult a database. If you want to programmatically access their service, the obvious way is to [use their API](http://dev.elsevier.com/api_docs.html), which will mostly requires sending HTTP requests and parsing the HTTP response. You can do this with the standard lib's modules, but you'll certainly save a lot of time using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead. And you'll certainly want to get some understanding of the [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) before...